# Convert all checkbox to one string

Tags: string, vba, ms-access

I am using Ms Access and a have one form with 10 checkboxes on it and a button. The user may check from 1 to 10 checkboxes. Every checkbox represent a word. I need a code to loop to all checkboxes from 1 to 10 and to give me a string so I can parse it to a module a have.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim str1, str2, str3, str4, str5 As String
Dim strString As String

If chB1 = True Then
str1 = "111 - "
End If

If chB2 = True Then
str2 = "222 - "
End If

If chB3 = True Then
str3 = "333 - "
End If

If chB4 = True Then
str4 = "444 - "
End If

If chB5 = True Then
str5 = "555 - "
End If

strString = str1 & str2 & str3 & str4 & str5 & Date
Debug.Print strString

End Sub
```

I am having this right now. Can I do it with another way?
Any help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `CheckBox1` is checked, its value will be `True`. If its value is `True`, you want to concatenate its `Caption` into your result string. Continue with `CheckBox2`. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Add code. Can I do it with loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have each `CheckBox` control have its associated string somewhere - could be its `Caption`, could be its `Tag`, whatever - you need a way to get that string from the checkbox itself, if you want to avoid having to hard-code it.

Then you can iterate your checkboxes, and with a dynamic array that you resize to the number of checked boxes, you can store the associated strings in each array index.

```
Dim items(), itemCount As Long
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control, chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'iterate all form controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then 'only care for checkboxes
        Set chkBox = ctrl ' type cast to the MSForms.CheckBox interface
        If chkBox.Value Then 'only care for checked checkboxes
            itemCount = itemCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve items(1 To itemCount)
            items(itemCount) = chkBox.Tag 'or whatever you've mapped the strings to
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Then you can join the array elements with whatever separator you want to use, with the `VBA.Strings.Join` function:

```
Debug.Print Join(items, " - ")
```